# From a JSON object: '0' is false?

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a JSON object with this properties

```
id: "23132772"
isAvailable: "1",
isSelected: "0",
maxPoints: "0",
minPoints: "0",
name: "Parlay",
placeBetIsAvailable: "0"
```

this JSON comes from an object named `betType`

so lets say I want to work with `placeBetIsAvailable` when it is `false`.

As you see, there I have `placeBetIsAvailable: "0"`

so, in my code, am I able to do:

`if(!betType.placeBetIsAvailable)` ?

or should I specify

`if(betType.placeBetIsAvailable === '0')` ?

Comment: technically, `=== '0'` is correct, but `0 == '0'` is ALSO true in javascript.

Comment: _"I am getting a JSON object"._ JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" (it's a String), but an Object is... an Object you can manipulate. So, which one is it?

Comment: Strings are only false if they are empty or null.
So the second approach is correct.

Comment: Encoding values that seem to be ordinary numbers as strings seems strange. Why aren't they numbers?

Comment: @SebastianNette A "string" which is null is also true (mean a string which "is" null is a string with written "null" in it!)%)P.

Comment: You could also do `!+betType.placeBetIsAvailable` which would convert your string `"0"` (which is truthy) into the number `0` which is falsy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `"0"` is *truthy* in JavaScript, while the number `0` is not. If your JSON is being encoded with zeros in quotes, then they're non-empty strings.

Comment: One of the oddities with JavaScript: the difference between forms like `"0" == false` (-> `true`) and `if (!"0")` (-> `if(false)`) is the latter does not apply the type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

If it were a number and not a string you could do that, but since it is a string with character in the string(not empty string ''), it is no longer falsey. To fix this you could do this

```
if(!parseInt(betType.placeBetIsAvailable))
```

or

```
if(!+betType.placeBetIsAvailable)
```

which is probably more work than just doing

```
if(betType.placeBetIsAvailable === '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

The construct `if(!betType.placeBetIsAvailable)` is inappropriate if you are using the strings "0" and "1" to encode `true` and `false`. Type this in your address bar to see why.

```
javascript:alert(["0", !"0", "1", !"1"])
```

Basically, !"0" and !"1" both evaluate to `false`.

If you *really* cannot do anything about the JSON returned by the server, you should use the form `if(betType.placeBetIsAvailable === '0')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting it to number and use ! to convert it to boolean

```
if(!!Number(betType.placeBetIsAvailable))
```